# Как заставить кнопку выполнять sql запрос

Tags: python, mysql, sql, ооп, pyqt5

Не понимаю как в *PyQt* заставить кнопку при нажатии выполнять `sql` запрос. Я лютый дилетант, но я пытался читать документацию и ничего не понял. 
По идее надо передавать в клик кнопки функцию, которая что-то делает, однако при нажатии приложение крашится с кодом - `1073740791 (0xC0000409)`.

```
import sys
from dbconfig import dbconfig
import mysql.connector
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        connection = mysql.connector.connect(**dbconfig)
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        loadUi("interface.ui", self)
        self.loadData(cursor, connection)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.buttonclick)

    def loadData(self, cursor, connection):
        cursor.execute("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS testdb")
        cursor.execute("USE testdb")
        connection.commit()

    def buttonclick(self, cursor, connection):
        cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, col2 INT)")
        connection.commit()
        print("success")


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    application = MainWindow()
    application.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Ничего особенного, просто файл подключения

```
dbconfig = {'host': '127.0.0.1',
            'user': 'root',
            'password': '123123', }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь принять в функции buttonclick cursor и connection, а в бинде их не передаете. попробуйте так:

```
import sys
from dbconfig import dbconfig
import mysql.connector
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        self.connection = mysql.connector.connect(**dbconfig)
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        loadUi("interface.ui", self)
        self.loadData()
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.buttonclick)

    def loadData(self):
        self.cursor.execute("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS testdb")
        self.cursor.execute("USE testdb")
        self.connection.commit()

    def buttonclick(self):
        self.cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, col2 INT)")
        self.connection.commit()
        print("success")


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    application = MainWindow()
    application.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: Оно работает. Огромное человеческое спасибо. Только я не совсем понял, почему лишь из-за приписки self все заработало и почему в функции не надо теперь передавать переменные

Comment: почитайте про ООп в pythone, думаю, что вы еще зеленый в этой теме, без обид))

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы получить реальную ошибку запустите ваше приложение в консоли/терминале/CMD.

Я не могу проверить ваше приложение, но попробуйте так:

```
import sys
from dbconfig import dbconfig
import mysql.connector
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        loadUi("interface.ui", self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.buttonclick)

# ----> vvvvv <--------------------------------------------------------        
        self.connection = mysql.connector.connect(**dbconfig)
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()
# ----> ^^^^^ <-------------------------------------------------------- 
 
        self.loadData()

    def loadData(self):
        self.cursor.execute("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS testdb")
        self.cursor.execute("USE testdb")
        self.connection.commit()

    def buttonclick(self):
        self.cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, col2 INT)")
        self.connection.commit()
        print("success")


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    application = MainWindow()
    application.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```